# DIV (pos:absolute) getting overlapped on jquery .slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning, overlapping

I am extremely new to web development and I am drilling my head into a wall right now.  I know I am missing something crucial and likely very simple.  Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <div id='content'>

        <div id='leftColumn'>php includes</div>
            <script></script>  //jQuery script to slideToggle a div on the leftColumn.
        <div id='page'>php includes</div>

    </div>
    <div id='footer'>php includes</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#leftColumn {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:70px;
        width:200px;
}
    #leftColumn1 {
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
    }
    #leftColumn2 {
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
    }
#content {
        z-index:-1;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top:0px;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
        bottom:1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

When I toggle the sideColumn div to appear, the footer stays where the bottom of the page used to be probably due to

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
        bottom:1px;
```

The #sideColumn drops down (like it should) and overlaps #footer(like it shouldn't).  I have been messing with positions of these elements to no avail.  Any advice or maybe a finger pointing to where I can read up on an existing solution?  Thanks in advance.

**fiddle:**
**http://jsfiddle.net/ETHER34L/ymsuv0m6/3/**

Comment: provide fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I coded html w3schools made this all "click."

[w3schools css reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

I don't know what you're picturing so I'll leave tinkering up to you...I'd try the different attribute values and see what happens.

Comment: Tried `float:left` on the footer and its all working flawless now.  Should have tried that earlier.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need the followng CSS:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

But a jsfiddle would be nice.

If you turn on the inspector in firefox, select the body, and then expand your div, you may notice the body doesn't get any taller even though it would seem like it should. This is very annoying, and not consistent across browsers. Actually, getting a footer to always remain at the bottom even when the content isn't tall enough is an oddly difficult problem and all the ways to get it to do so introduce other problems depending on what you need to do (for example: make javascript scroll the page to a certain location).

Edit:

This kind of page structure should suit your needs:

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
  <div id="nav">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left{
  min-height: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
#main{
  min-height: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 80%
}
#footer{
    clear: both;
}
```

You may want to use exact values for left and main's widths, or an exact value for left but calc(100% - [left's width]) for main's width. Or, [display:table](http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/) variants

Comment: just added to my CSS.  no luck.  I don't need the footer to expand with the page, that's why its givin me a hard time.  I need it to expand with the leftColumn

Comment: Perhaps try a structure where the left column and main body are side-by side divs and the footer is just the next div but has clear: both; in it's css. This will work well except when the page is not very tall the footer doesn't stick to the bottom of the browser, which isn't a big problem. Can't make code blocks in comments on here for some reason so I'll edit my answer but it's a fairly common approach.

Comment: Jacob, thanks for the response.  I originally had the exact structure you describe.  However, I need to be able to assign the attribute `z-index` so that the border shadows on the other elements drops correctly.  Since changing to my current structure, the shadows drop perfectly, but the page is acting lame.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a little vague as to how you want the final result to look. 
I've created a simple fiddle where I removed the absolute positioning and floated the left column, and the slideToggle does not cause the left column to overlap the footer.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfsmqwo3/)

I've added spacing and colors to see how the boundaries look on the divs.

```
#footer {
    background-color: red; /* for illustrative purposes */
    height: 200px; /* for illustrative purposes */
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

#leftColumn {
    width:200px; 
    background-color: yellow; /* for illustrative purposes */
    height: 200px; /* for illustrative purposes */
    float:left;    
}
```

Was the footer overlap the only issue?

Comment: the footer overlap is my only issue